# How to use Spring Security's CSRF feature for stateless endpoints?

Tags: java, spring-security, csrf

I'm using Spring Security with a stateless web service. I'd like to use the CSRF features in Spring Security 3.2. Is that possible with a stateless web app?

This is the relevant Java Config, since I've had to disable CSRF for the time being.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .sessionFixation().none().and()
            .csrf().disable();
}
```

Comment: Is your web service to be used within a web browser at all?

Comment: Yes. Primarily used in a single page web app (AngularJS)

Comment: See how: http://blog.jdriven.com/2014/10/stateless-spring-security-part-1-stateless-csrf-protection/

Answer (score 3):

If your service is really stateless, CSRF protection might not make sense at all. As long as the server does not use cookies to identify/authenticate the user, your service is not vulnerable to CSRF attacks.

For a detailed explanation, see http://sitr.us/2011/08/26/cookies-are-bad-for-you.html

Answer (score 0):

if your application or API is going to be accessed by a browser, you need CSRF protection.

Reference demos : spring-security-and-angular-js

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_the_login_page_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_ii

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, this only is required if your application stores tokens in cookies. I recently had to implement this with Spring Security 6 so here is what I went with (solution for an application which does it's own authentication).

The problem I found with disabling CSRF from Spring Security completely and checking CSRF token with custom filter (as done in this [article](http://blog.jdriven.com/2014/10/stateless-spring-security-part-1-stateless-csrf-protection/)) is that it also turns off revoking cookies `onAuthentication`, which could allow session fixation attack - where an attacker

- injects a CSRF token into victim's browser
- waits for the victim to login
- uses another Form POST to get the victim to perform an action with still UNchanged CSRF token.

Because of this reason, CSRF token should always be changed on principal change.

But with Stateless application, the `onAuthentication` is triggered on every request - which also doesn't work, since that would revoke the Csrf-Token everytime and leave FrontEnd without Csrf-Token after every successful request (and then again keep issuing it for safe requests like GET, resulting in a mess where sometimes token is there and sometimes not). The correct behavior is of course to only revoke it once on principal change.

### Solution:

In accordance with [Spring Security Docu for SPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript-spa) I implemented `CsrfCookieFilter` and `CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler` which I then add to `HttpSecurity`:

```java
public class CsrfCookieFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute("_csrf");
        // Render the token value to a cookie by causing the deferred token to be loaded
        csrfToken.getToken();
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

```java
public class SpaCsrfTokenRequestHandler extends CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler {
    private final CsrfTokenRequestHandler delegate = new XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response,
                       Supplier<CsrfToken> csrfToken) {
        /*
         * Always use XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler to provide BREACH protection of
         * the CsrfToken when it is rendered in the response body.
         */
        this.delegate.handle(request, response, csrfToken);
    }

    @Override
    public String resolveCsrfTokenValue(HttpServletRequest request, CsrfToken csrfToken) {
        /*
         * If the request contains a request header, use CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler
         * to resolve the CsrfToken. This applies when a single-page application includes
         * the header value automatically, which was obtained via a cookie containing the
         * raw CsrfToken.
         */
        if (StringUtils.hasText(request.getHeader(csrfToken.getHeaderName()))) {
            return super.resolveCsrfTokenValue(request, csrfToken);
        }
        /*
         * In all other cases (e.g. if the request contains a request parameter), use
         * XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler to resolve the CsrfToken. This applies
         * when a server-side rendered form includes the _csrf request parameter as a
         * hidden input.
         */
        return this.delegate.resolveCsrfTokenValue(request, csrfToken);
    }
}
```

Then I add these to HttpSecurity:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain apiFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .csrf(csrf -> {
             CookieCsrfTokenRepository cookieCsrfTokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
             cookieCsrfTokenRepository.setCookiePath("/");
                    
             csrf.csrfTokenRepository(cookieCsrfTokenRepository)
                 .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new SpaCsrfTokenRequestHandler())
                 .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy()); // this turns OFF the onAuthenticate CSRF cookie revocation
         }) 
        .sessionManagement(s -> s.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(customizer -> customizer.anyRequest().authenticated())
        .build();
}
```

I then trigger `onAuthentication` manually after the initial JWT token issuing (so very first login) in order to revoke the CSRF tokens on principal change. For this I create first the following beans:

```java
@Bean
public CookieCsrfTokenRepository cookieCsrfTokenRepository() {
    CookieCsrfTokenRepository cookieCsrfTokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
    cookieCsrfTokenRepository.setCookiePath("/");
    return cookieCsrfTokenRepository;
}

@Bean
public CsrfAuthenticationStrategy csrfAuthenticationStrategy(CookieCsrfTokenRepository cookieCsrfTokenRepository) {
    return new CsrfAuthenticationStrategy(cookieCsrfTokenRepository);
}
```

and the call `onAuthentication` after initial login:

```java
// called in the method that does the initial login (after Tokens are first created)
csrfAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(authentication, request, response);
```

This revokes the Csrf-Token Cookie, and the Client will have to make another GET request after logging in (as it should be).

---

#### FrontSide (Angular) changes:

```js
@Injectable()
export class CsrfTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  /**
   * Methods allowed in Backend {@link CsrfFilter.DefaultRequiresCsrfMatcher#allowedMethods}
   */
  private readonly CSRF_ALLOWED_METHODS = ["GET", "HEAD", "TRACE", "OPTIONS"]
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const xsrfTokenFromCookie = this.getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');
    // IF not a CSRF Allowed method (e.g. POST, PUT or DELETE), and XSRF-TOKEN is present
    if (!this.CSRF_ALLOWED_METHODS.includes(req.method) && xsrfTokenFromCookie) {
      // Clone the request and add X-XSRF-TOKEN header
      const modifiedReq = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', xsrfTokenFromCookie)
      });
      // Pass the modified request to the next handler
      return next.handle(modifiedReq);
    }
    // If it's a GET request, pass the original request
    return next.handle(req);
  }

  getCookie(name: string): string | undefined {
    const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (let cookie of cookies) {
      const [cookieName, cookieValue] = cookie.trim().split('=');
      if (cookieName === name) {
        return cookieValue;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

And of course don't forget to add it to providers:

```js
...
providers: [
  {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CsrfTokenInterceptor, multi:true}
],
...
```

Also you will need to add the option `withCredentials: true`, for the requests to include the CSRF token.

There is a [blog post](https://blog.asgarov1.com/?post=2024-02-18_spring_security_cors_and_csrf_configuration_with_stateless_jwt_application.md), that explains the background a bit more in detail